# Training a model - Redundant Pictures from Different Angles

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, object-detection

I want to create my own Tensorflow model for a set images.  This set would consist of approximately 50 different classifications to choose from.

Would there be any benefit/harm to training a model on the same classification image but say from a different view angle?

For example, I want to classify a type of frog.  I have pictures from the front, side, and back of the same frog.  Should I only use the picture from the front, all, or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. This is quite common in CV applications. Check out [Keras' options for image pre-processinng](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) to get a better idea of what is possible/common.